# reordering categorical variable column from alphabetical for ggplot in R

Tags: r

i have a large dataframe that looks like this:

df <- data.frame(wealth = c(low, med, high), income = c(50000, 100000, 150000))

when I code a ggplot and enter wealth as an x or y variable, it lists high first since it is alphabetical.

how can I manual change the order that it lists the wealth variable in ggplot to low, med, high?

Comment: change it to a factor with `levels = c("low", "med"", high")`

Comment: Specifically, `df$wealth <- factor(df$wealth, levels = c("low", "med"", high"))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(wealth = c("low", "med", "high"), income = c(50000, 100000, 150000))
df$wealth_f <- factor(df$wealth, levels = c("low", "med", "high"))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = wealth_f, y = income)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this did it!